# Setting up RDF class instances in KOMMA

Tags: eclipse, semantic-web

Looking at the documentation for KOMMA plug-in for Eclipse IDE, there doesn't seem to be any way of setting up class instances in its OWL editor, only through Java code:
http://komma.enilink.net/docs/editors/owl_editor/index.html.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the views called "Instances" or "Instance Tree" to create instances of RDFS/OWL classes. First select a class, for example in the classes view, and then use one of the plus buttons to create a corresponding instance.